# Render re-usable framework within a container defined by the main app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm planning to program a re-usable framework that manages its own views.
To get started, I already managed to get the static library and a separate bundle (assets etc) working fine.

What I'm trying to do now is somewhat comparable to the behavior of a jQuery plugin. The main application that depends on my framework (and bundle) should define an element in its view that it can hand over to my framework as a reference. The framework will then render itself within this element.

It is necessary that the main application can handle itself how that container is being displayed (overlaying the main app entirely, or being displayed in only a certain portion of the main app...)

I was already looking at "Container Views" but am not sure if this is the suggested approach to accomplish this. Any ideas, or resources / tutorials that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: The way you usually do this on iOS is that your framework provides an `UIView` object. The app sets properties on the view object to configure it appropriately and adds it to its own view hierarchy (so it controls how it is displayed). It's the same thing as using a view provided by UIKit... Could you please make the question more detailed, if that doesn't answer it?

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I understand the basic concept behind your suggested approach, but am having difficulties putting it all together. I'll need to play around with views for a bit to come up with a more precise question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the approach suggested by Thomas, I was able to put it all together.

Basically, the app itself defines a UIView and hands off a reference to it to the framework. The framework is then able to put its content inside this UIView.